# parameter passing between two android devices over the internet

Tags: android, database, networking

I am new to Android so, sorry if I do not use technical terms.

Basically I want to pass parameters from one Android device to another over the internet. I did so by making a database on a free hosting site and PHP pages to store and retrieve the data from database.

But the problem is that I want the parameters to be sent and received with a max delay of 2 sec. Sometimes I do get that but sometimes I do not receive any parameter for 8-10 sec.

So what can I do now? Should I go for enterprise level database for performance or should I go for any other method? I just want to send single character parameters such as 'a','b','c' from one Android device to another on button click.

Comment: Do you want to share data of your application with other apps?

Comment: Did you try using FireBase?

Comment: I think you can do this with GCM or FireBase.

Comment: Are you sure the database is the problem? More likely it's the internet connection itself. If the Android devices are near each other, maybe NFC or [peer-to-peer WiFi](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html) could help.